# File Uploading in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I want to upload a particular file on server in Silverlight 4,

Simply, to upload any file we can use the "Browse" button.
When you click on this button we can get the file directory and choose any file & we can upload the particular file.

i have coded on browse button

```
 private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var fileDialog =new OpenFileDialog();
            fileDialog.ShowDialog();
            fileDialog.Multiselect = true;
            txtUploader.Text = fileDialog.File.DirectoryName;
            fileDialog.File.CopyTo("C:/UploadedFiles");
        }
```

here the problem is, only the dialog box is opening
not able to select multiple file,
not getting path,
not able to upload the file to specified location.

Comment: It's been a while since I did SL, but I do remember selecting files from a user's machine was severely restricted due to security. Also calling CopyTo with a C:\ path isn't really uploading it, that C:\ path will be on the user's machine (and that's almost certainly a path you don't have access to, to boot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the order that you are setting up your [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog.aspx) Box.

Also you are returning a [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) object. If you are going to return multiple files you need use Files instead of File it will return a collection of FileInfo objects. You can then iterate over the collection to get your information. In testing out the code I was getting a Security Exception on reading the path of the files, you do not have the permissions needed to do what you want to do per @MattGreer's comment.

Edit added from @AnthonyWJones comment.

There is not any way to do what you are trying to do, except to create an OOB with elevated trust, and that will limit you to the users MyDocuments Folder.

[image]

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        var fileDialog =new OpenFileDialog(); 
        fileDialog.Multiselect = true; 
        fileDialog.ShowDialog(); 

        IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo>  files = fileDialog.Files;
        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
        {
           txtUploader.Text = fi.DirectoryName;
           fi.CopyTo("C:/UploadedFiles");     
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Mark:  There isn't any way to get the "permissions" to what the rest of the code is doing in SL.  The closest you can come is to have it as OOB with Elevated Trust and be moving files about within the users `MyDocuments` area.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Thanks for the info, will modify answer to state such.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones What is OOB (out of browser ?) if so, then there isn't any possible way to get permission by browser?